# Why this case of generic type instantiation doesn't work?

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

I wrote this simplified code to explain the issue I am facing. My question is at the bottom.

```
public abstract class Creator<T> : UnityEngine.Object
 where T :UnityEngine.Object, new()
{
    public static T CreateInstance()
    {
        T instance = new T(); // -> Here's the issue! always null

        return instance;
    }
}

public class ConcreteCreator : Creator<ConcreteCreator>
{
}
```

Whenever I invoke CreateInstance, the result is always null. This is because the instantiation of the generic type T is always returning null:

T instance = new T(); //->Here's the problem, this returns null every time

I tried with different subclasses. I also tried using Activator.CreateInstance() instead of new T(). But **nothing worked until I removed the UnityEngine.Object class constraint from the generic type T**. Like this:

```
public abstract class Creator<T> : UnityEngine.Object where T : new()

{...}
```

Just then, everything worked as expected.

So, my question is:

Why is the instantiation of a generic type (using the parameterless constructor) returning null, when the type is constrained to be a subclass of UnityEngine.Object?

Comment: Your `MySingleton` type is *incapable* of creating a singleton.  Every type used with it must by definition have a public constructor, which means that by definition you cannot prevent multiple instances from being created.

Comment: The C# `new` operator can only return a non-`null` value. Please post a code example showing what you're actually doing. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. (Servy's point is also valid, but if we get away from the idea that you're making a singleton, you still seem to have a problem).

Comment: Thanks Servy and Peter. I wrote new code to make my question clearer. I tested that code too and the problem persists

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova: You probably should convert your comment to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `UnityEngine.Object` overrides 
`==` operator and pretends to be null even if it isn't. See [New UnityEngine.Object is Null](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/new-unityengine-object-is-null.98150/)
for more details.
In any case it has nothing to do with generics or c#.